# WebStorm - Vim like feature "Sort"

Tags: editor, webstorm

Is there any **shortcut** to sort code lines in WebStorm?

For instance, let's assume I have the three `imports a, b, c` and I'd like to sort them

```
import c
import b
import a
```

highlight `import c, import b, import a + sort` + **shortcut**

```
import a 
import b
import c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality in WebStorm that would allow sorting custom lines of text/code.

You can install and use **String Manipulation plugin** that has lots of useful actions for strings -- including sorting them.

[image]